# Regex to find string start with @ and end with @ example @string demo@ in string

Tags: regex, string

Make Regex to find string start with '@' and end with '@' example @string demo@   in string.

Comment: Is that an order?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes for example :- I'm finding a @regular expression@ which adheres below rules.In this example i want to find out string reguler expression which start from "@" end with "@".It could be one word or or a string which start and end with @

Comment: Yes for example :- I'm finding a #regular expression# which adheres below rules.In this example i want to find out string reguler expression which start from "#" end with "#".It could be one word or or a string which start and end with # @ClasG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/\s*(@[^@]*@)\s*/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6Qpv2/1)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ,its really work for me.Just i need one alternative solution. I want to make regex for particuler dynamic string .For Example This example illustrates the features and core functionality. in this i want make regex for "Core" which can be dynamic .Please give suggestion for it YouneL

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic, is text changes ? can you give examples of input text and output

Comment: Is it possible to make regex for dynamic word .I have an array of match string.For example arrLink ="really","need","one","the". and an array for listing arrList="I am really happy", "i need this pen".so in this array i have to match words from arrlink .it could be anything.i hope you understand the scenerio @younel

Comment: Yes you can, just iterate over arrLink and arrList and check `link` existence in each `list`, something like this in javascript: `var rgx = new RegExp(link); return rgx.test(list);` it returns true if `link` has been found in `list`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex.

```
^@.*@$
```

Example

```
String s1 = new String("@helloaaaaaa@"); //input string to be tested
boolean result = s1.matches("^@.*@$"); //if input matches i.e (true or false)
```

Comment: String couldbe like this #regular expression# , #regular# and #regular expression for#